# Create indeterminate JProgressBar Popup/modal dialog

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

How can I create a popup window/modal dialog with an indeterminate progressbar running ?

I can´t even manage to create a indeterminate progressbar that isn´t running all the time in a simple window...

Thats the best result I´ve got so far:

```
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
panel_3.add(progressBar);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: so doesn't this work ? also you should set intermediate to true.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  In addition to the advice of @FastSnail, a common problem with seeing a progress bar is that of 'blocking the EDT'.  It is commonly mentioned on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To such a vague question I can only give some guidelines as an answer.

The `JProgressBar` has a method `setIndeterminate(Boolean);`, which you can use.

Now the bigger problem you face with progressbars is that to be able to see the progress animation *the long-running operation that is done while progressbar is shown must be run in a non-gui thread*. I will have to refer you to read about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

The basic steps for the modal dialog with a progressbar are

1. Create a JDialog
2. Set it modal (read the JDialog API)
3. Give it a `Layout`
4. Insert the progressbar as is, or inside for example a `JPanel` that has a suitable `Layout`. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) are your options.
5. Launch your long-running task in a new thread with a `SwingWorker` or something else